# Page number group in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

[Please find the below picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkzS9.png)

It possible to do in MS Access Query. Kindly help me to resolved this issue.

```
Page     Page Breakup
0        0-20
21       21-50
51       51-100
101      101-500
501      500 >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will do that:

```sql
SELECT 
    PageGroup.Page, 
    IIf(
        (Select First(Page) From PageGroup As T Where T.Page > PageGroup.Page) Is Null,
        CStr([Page] - 1) & " >",
        CStr([Page]) & "-" & (Select Min(Page) - 1 From PageGroup As T Where T.Page > PageGroup.Page)) AS [Page Breakup]
FROM 
    PageGroup;
```